# Plot separate histograms from dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, histogram

I have a data frame table "pandastable3" that looks like this:

[image]

I would like to plot histograms of values for all the columns separately, but so far I am able to get only a single figure containing all the plots together with this to plot the first 3 columns:

```
pandastable3.hist(layout=(1,2,3))
```

But I am not sure I am doing that correctly as I cannot visualize anything.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose `diff()` gives different plots for each column:

```
pandastable3.diff().hist()
```

Comment: Also refer https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html